# Mantener color en una fila con GridView

Tags: c#, sql, windows

Tengo un código, si la celda se edita, esta se marca de color verde, si la celda se marca con problema (Se despliega un menú para marcarla) se pinta de rojo, pero a la hora de refrescar el Form se pierden los colores, ¿Alguien sabe cómo se pueden mantener?, adjunto ejemplo cúando se marca problema:

```
foreach (GridViewCellInfo cell in grdRP.SelectedRows[0].Cells)
                {
                    cell.Style.CustomizeFill = true;
                    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.IndianRed;
                    cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    cell.Style.NumberOfColors = 1;
                    cell.Style.DrawFill = true;
                }
```

¿Algún ejemplo o código que pueda guardarme el color de la fila cada vez que inicia el form?, ejemplo:

[image: Ejemplo]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUL3m.png

Comment: que quiere decir al refrescar el form? donde esta ubicado ese codigo que mostras?

Comment: Refrescar = Volvera  a abrir, el código está ubicado en el Form

Comment: el form es muy grande.. donde esta ubicado ese codigo? en que metodo del form? y cuando volves a abrir el form, donde guardaste la informacion de si algo esta editado o con error?

Comment: Tu código debe ir en el evento databindingcomplete del componente datagridview

Comment: Si Japv, ahí lo tengo, pero sólo me marca la columna que es == true, pero no toda la fila, o sea, solo me marca la columna, y yo necesito marque toda la fila

Comment: Deberias agregar el contexto completo donde se ejecuta el codigo, porque solo colocaste un foreach.

Comment: Revisa el evento [CellFormatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=netcore-3.1). Es ahi donde debes "pintar" tus celdas, para evitar que con cualquier redibujado del grid el formato se pierda